# Passing a Nullable Guid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, guid

I am trying to pass a nullable Guid and use it as the default for a field if it is not Null but I am getting an error.

Here is my code:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create(Guid? pTETrackingClassID)
        {
            PTETrackingClass model = new PTETrackingClass();
            if (pTETrackingClassID != null)
            {
                model.TrackingClassCode = pTETrackingClassID;
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

on this line

```
model.TrackingClassCode = pTETrackingClassID;
```

I am getting this error:

> cannot implicitly convert type System.Guid? to System.Guid

So then I tried this:

```
model.TrackingClassCode = new Guid(pTETrackingClassID);
```

and I am getting an error on that line too.  What am I missing?

Comment: Do you mean to do `model.TrackingClassCode = pTETrackingClassID.Value;`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nullable types are not assignable to their non-nullable equivalents. You need to extract the underlying value using the `Value` property.

```
model.TrackingClassCode = pTETrackingClassID.Value;
```

As **juharr** mentions is his comment, you will get the same result by explicitly casting the nullable object.

```
model.TrackingClassCode = (Guid)pTETrackingClassID;
```

Comment: Or explicitly cast them `model.TrackingClassCode = (Guid)pTETrackingClassID;`

Comment: @juharr Thanks for the comment. I'll add this to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if (pTETrackingClassID.HasValue)
            {
                model.TrackingClassCode = pTETrackingClassID.Value;
            }
```

Comment: The downvote happened before your edit (it wasn't me) :-)